# disable "unsafe statement for binary logging" In mysql

Tags: mysql

How do i disable `unsafe statement for binary logging` Warning Message in Error log in `MySQL` `5.5` version.
I don't want to change my `binlog` format to Row or Mixed Mode.

In `Percona` there is variable `log_warnings_suppress = 1592`
Is there anything like this in `MySQL` ?

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: Suggestion: don't just hide the warning, fix it. It's trying to tell you something, so listen to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting that from a `DELETE` with a `LIMIT`, there is a workaround.

1. Do a `SELECT` with the same `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to get the `id` or range of ids that need to be deleted.
2. Perform the `DELETE` with that `id` or `IN ( ... )` or `id BETWEEN ... AND ...`.

Answer (score 0):

@ircmaxwell he isn't actually hiding the warning (in this case) he is suppressing a warning that is not a requirement for his set up. This is warning on an unsafe 'binary log statement', which could just be an update with a limit clause.. for example. 
Its normally 'fixed' by setting replicatuion to 'row' or 'mixed'. If that is not wanted, then Percona came up with the solution to 'hide' it.